# how to hide or show image with just one button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, wpf-controls

I am adding the button and image element using code. My wpf application is able to display an image stored on my project when I click the button. I want to hide the displayed image if I clicked the button again. How will I be able to achieve this if I only have one event handler for my button?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid_parent.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(150, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        grid_parent.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(150, GridUnitType.Auto)});

        Button btn_submit = new Button { Content = "Submit" };
        btn_submit.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        Grid.SetRow(btn_submit, 1);
        btn_submit.Click += btn_submit_Click;
        grid_parent.Children.Add(btn_submit);
    }

    void btn_submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/AddControlsThroughClass;component/images/julie.jpg", UriKind.Relative)) };       
        image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        Grid.SetRow(image, 0);
        grid_parent.Children.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677906/wpf-toggle-button-checked-uchecked-event-with-one-handler

Comment: Or you can check the image property. if visible then make it disappear and vice vers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` control has no notion of when it has been clicked. Instead of using a regular `Button`, it would make more sense for you to use a `ToggleButton`, which *does* know when it has been clicked. The `ToggleButton` class has an `IsChecked` property that will be set to `true` after the first click and back to `false` after another click. Therefore there is a very simple solution using this `ToggleButton` property:

```
image.Visibility = toggleButton.IsChecked ? Visiblity.Visible : Visiblity.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a button however you can do also with keypreview property

Here is a code with keypreview

```
    private void HideShow(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    }
```

From the properties of your form add to keydown propery you can hide and show your picture

Or you can do by a button

by this code

```
pictureBox1.Visible = !pictureBox1.Visible
```

each time you click the button it will be visible or invisible)

Comment: -1 This is WPF, not Winforms... look at the question tags. you do *not* set `Visibilty` like that in WPF.